# Premiere video layers in AE dynamic link

Tags: after-effects, video-editing, adobe-premiere

I have a sequence in Premiere with 4 video layers. It's all footage with a green screen and want to key it out with AE but after importing the premiere file in AE it's just on layer. Do I need to make a sequence for each layer or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When you select Replace with After Effects Composition in Premiere, it will move all selected media to After Effects and leave behind a single layer in Premiere.  It's essentially copying the media to Ae and importing the Ae project into premiere.  You can do your keying in Ae and save, and it will update in Premiere.  This workflow means you don't be able to make edit adjustments within your replacement selection in Premiere, so you should use this method to first key out all your footage, then do your edits to the replacement layer inside Premiere.